# image in circle frame iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiimageview, uiimage

i have uitableview with a list of contact. I would like to have the image of each contact in an circle frame like in the login screen of mavericks. Any suggestions how to do this in an uitableviewCell ?

[image]

Comment: if you revolve your question with my answer accept it plz

Answer (score 75, accepted):

I presume that you have your imageView inside your Cell, so what your have just to do for have the same effect is use a invisible border. Use this code for make this effect:

```
cell.yourImageView.layer.cornerRadius = cell.yourImageView.frame.size.height /2;
cell.yourImageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
cell.yourImageView.layer.borderWidth = 0;
```

Your UIImageView must have the same height and width also you have to import the quartzCore framework in your project

Comment: Is it possible to set these changes in the storyboard? or the only solution is in code?

Comment: only code solution :/

Comment: Please consider performance when it's in a scroll view(such as uitableview).

Comment: If you use a storyboard prototype for the cell, you can set those properties in "User Defined Runtime Attributes"

Answer (score 1):

apparently i can make a rounded rect like this

```
float fw, fh;
if (ovalWidth == 0 || ovalHeight == 0) {
    CGContextAddRect(context, rect);
    return;
}
CGContextSaveGState(context);
CGContextTranslateCTM (context, CGRectGetMinX(rect), CGRectGetMinY(rect));
CGContextScaleCTM (context, ovalWidth, ovalHeight);
fw = CGRectGetWidth (rect) / ovalWidth;
fh = CGRectGetHeight (rect) / ovalHeight;
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, fw, fh/2);
CGContextAddArcToPoint(context, fw, fh, fw/2, fh, 1);
CGContextAddArcToPoint(context, 0, fh, 0, fh/2, 1);
CGContextAddArcToPoint(context, 0, 0, fw/2, 0, 1);
CGContextAddArcToPoint(context, fw, 0, fw, fh/2, 1);
CGContextClosePath(context);
CGContextRestoreGState(context);
```

and then put the image inside, it will be automatically clipped:

```
 CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSaveGState(context);
addRoundedRectToPath(context, self.frame, 10, 10);
CGContextClip(context);
[image drawInRect:self.frame];
CGContextRestoreGState(context);
```