# Add image circle in UIImageView using objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiimageview

I have a `UIImageView` and this is my code to show image :

```
callRecImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"call_accept.png"]];
        [callRecImage setFrame:CGRectMake(133,top, 36, 40)];
        [self.view addSubview: callRecImage];
```

To add circle around image I did this :

```
callRecImage.layer.cornerRadius = callRecImage.frame.size.width /2;       callRecImage.layer.borderWidth = 2.0f;
callRecImage.layer.borderColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor; callRecImage.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

my image view is :[image]

my output is :
[image]

I want to add a circle to my `UIImageView`, I have followed this link [image in circle frame iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19640766/image-in-circle-frame-ios) but it's working as I expected

I want a big circle around the phone image. any kind of help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try to have your UIImageView frame in a square, so 36, 36 or 40, 40

Comment: i have tried but i am failed

Answer (score 0):

```
[callRecImage setFrame:CGRectMake(133,top, 36, 40)];
//Set Height and width equal
//Like 
[callRecImage setFrame:CGRectMake(133,top, 40, 40)];
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you go for `layer.cornerRadius` for the same view then circle will be always smaller then the view rectangle so use one of these two solution.

> I have tested and both the solutions are in working condition

1. Use following code to change `UIViewContentMode` of your image and increase your `UIImageView` frame size (height and width, both should be in equal)

   ```
   callRecImage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
   ```

   So that if you increase the `UIImageView` frame size, It will keep your image in center and won't stretch your image inside `UIImageView`

   ```
   UIImageView *callRecImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(133, top, 60, 60)];
   callRecImage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
   [callRecImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"call_accept.png"]];
   callRecImage.layer.cornerRadius = callRecImage.frame.size.width /2;
   callRecImage.layer.borderWidth = 2.0f;
   callRecImage.layer.borderColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor; 
   callRecImage.clipsToBounds = YES;
   [self.view addSubview: callRecImage];
   ```

**or**

2. Add one `UIView` as superview of your `UIImageView` and add `layer.cornerRadius` to that `UIView`

   ```
   UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(133, top, 60, 60)];
   UIImageView *callRecImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"call_accept.png"]];
   [callRecImage setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.size.width/2 - 36/2, view.frame.size.height/2 - 40/2, 36, 40)];
   view.layer.cornerRadius = view.frame.size.width /2;
   view.layer.borderWidth = 2.0f;
   view.layer.borderColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
   view.clipsToBounds = YES;
   [view addSubview: callRecImage];
   [self.view addSubview: view];
   ```

Answer (score 0):

use the following code

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

callRecImage.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
callRecImage.layer.cornerRadius = callRecImage.bounds.size.width/2;
callRecImage.layer.borderWidth = 2.0f;
callRecImage.layer.borderColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the below line to fill you image in `ImageView` only

```
callRecImage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
callRecImage.layer.backgroundColor=[[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];
callRecImage.layer.cornerRadius=20;
callRecImage.layer.borderWidth=2.0;
callRecImage.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
callRecImage.layer.borderColor=[[UIColor grayColor] CGColor]
```